# How to run a function on more than one file in AWK , when the answer of the function needs to be saved to use it on the next file?

Tags: linux, awk

### I wrote a function in AWk that will print the difference of two matrix
like f1 contains this matrix:
12 35 68 99
2 6
1
and f2 contains :
10 25 100
2 5 4
2
It will print in a file called tmp
2 10 -32 99
0 1 4

The code is :

```
function matrix_difference(file1,file2) {
printf "" > "tmp"
for (o=1;o<=NR;o++){
for (x=1;x<=NF;x++){
d=A[file1,o,x]
p=A[file2,o,x]
sum=d-p
printf sum " ">> "tmp"
}
print "" >> "tmp"
}
close("tmp")
}
```

I tried to write in AWK a code which gets a number of files that contains a matrix and prints : "The difference is (name of files with - between each name) is : "  it will print the difference in all the files . IF there are four files . f1 f2 f3 f4 it prints f1-f2-f3-f4
I tried to write the code but It doesn't work only on two files , I tried to do a loop but it doesn't work . It only works on two files only when I write matrix_difference(ARGV[1],ARGV[2]).

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
A[FILENAME,FNR,i]=$i
}
{
if ( FNR ==1)
print "The matrix " FILENAME " is :"
print $0
}
END{
matrix_difference(ARGV[1],ARGV[2])
for ( m=1;m<=NR;m++){
getline x <"tmp"
print x 
}

print " The matrix difference A-B-C-D is:"
}
function matrix_difference(file1,file2) {
printf "" > "tmp"
for (o=1;o<=NR;o++){
for (x=1;x<=NF;x++){
d=A[file1,o,x]
p=A[file2,o,x]
sum=d-p
printf sum " ">> "tmp"
}
print "" >> "tmp"
}
close("tmp")
}
```

also when I write the difference of Matrix then the files name don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

here is a sample code that will work with multiple files, after the first one, everything else will be subtracted.  Assumes all matrices have matching dimensions.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[NR,i]=$i; next} 
               {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[FNR,i]-=$i} 
       END     {for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) 
                  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) 
                     printf "%d%s",a[i,j],(j==NF?ORS:OFS)}' file1 file2
```

For the input files

```
==> file1 <==
1 2
3 4

==> file2 <==
1 0
0 1
```

script returns

```
0 2
3 3
```

try with more files

```
$ awk '...' file1 file2 file2

-1 2
3 2
```

you can convert to a function, not sure it helps!?

```
$ awk 'function sum(sign) {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[FNR,i]+=sign*$i}

       NR==FNR {sum(+1); next} 
               {sum(-1)} 
       END     {for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) 
                  for(j=1;j<=NF;j++) 
                    printf "%d%s",a[i,j],(j==NF?ORS:OFS)}'
```